# What is this 3 x 8 orange curved piece from?

Tags: set-identification

My dad recently gave me a large box of LEGO pieces that belong to sets. I found two pieces that appear to be the front of a car. I was wondering if you guys could help me out. I would love to know what it came from so I could maybe put it back together.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The pieces are
[41750 Wedge 8 x 3 x 2 Open Left](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=41750&colorID=4&in=A).
and
[41749 Wedge 8 x 3 x 2 Open Right](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=41749&colorID=4&in=A)
(respectively).

Those pieces have only been in the following 2 sets in that color:

### [3830-1 - The Bikini Bottom Express](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3830-1)

[image: 3830-1 - The Bikini Bottom Express]

### [7706-1 - Mobile Defense Tank](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7706-1)

[image: 7706-1 - Mobile Defense Tank]

Comment: I'm kinda new here, if the OP wanted to know what the pieces were, would you give them an element ID or would you pick a part number from one of the places that lists parts?

Comment: @Raystafarian I'd probably give them an official part number if possible and a link to the part on BrickLink.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: could you throw the part ID's in there somehow?